# Вертикальная прокрутка на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

При написании скрипта с прокруткой вертикальной столкнулся с проблемой, что прокрутка осуществляется не в то место, в которое нужно. У меня есть карта. На ней расположены геообъекты различные. Справа от карты есть блок. В нем находится множество блоков с описанием этих геообъектов. Я хочу, чтобы при клике на геообъект в правом блоке осуществлялась автоматическая прокрутка до нужного описания. Вот адрес сайта, чтобы было понятнее: [пример реализации](http://mylandbroker.ru/node?tid1%5B%5D=4&field_ploshad_value%5Bmin%5D=0&field_ploshad_value%5Bmax%5D=650&field_kadastr_value=&title=). Привожу часть кода, с помощью которого получилась таккая ситуация:

```
.add('click', function (e) {//при клике на геообъект
    var map = Drupal.geofieldYmap.data['geofield-ymap-catalog-page'].map; //получаю карту
    var result = ymaps.geoQuery(map.geoObjects);    //получаю все объекты на карте
    var res = document.getElementsByClassName("view-catalog")[1].getElementsByClassName("views-row"); //получаю список описаний, справа от карты
    if(existchange.length != 0){ //если не первый клик за сессию
        for(var i=0;i<existchange.length;i++)
            res[existchange[i]].style.background = 'none'; //возвращаю старое оформления для всех описаний того объекта, по которому был ранее совершен клик
        for(var i = 0; i< result._objects.length; i++){ //пока не пройдусь по всем объектам
            if(String(result._objects[i].properties._data.hintContent) == res[existchange[0]].getElementsByClassName("views-field-title")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML){  //ищу нужный(ые) мне
                result._objects[i].options.set('preset', OldPresetByClick); //возвращаю старый пресет
            }
        }
    }
    existchange = []; //обнуляю список порядковых номеров старых описаний
    for(var i=0; i<res.length;i++){ //пока не пройдусь по всем описаниям
        //ищу описание, которое соответствует тому объекту, на который только что совершили клик и как только нахожу такой(ие)
        if(String(e.get('target').properties._data.hintContent) == res[i].getElementsByClassName("views-field-title")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML)
            existchange.push(i);//запоминаю позицию этого(их) описания(ий)
        }
        res[existchange[0]].id = 'clickhover'; //добавляю к первому найденному описанию якорь для того, чтобы осуществить прокрутку до него
        for(var i=0;i<existchange.length;i++)
            res[existchange[i]].style.background = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.75)'; //меняю стиль для всех описаний    
        if(e.get('target').options._options.preset != 'custom#blockhover'){ //если клик совершен не второй раз по тому же геообъекту
            OldPresetByClick = OldPresetByHover; //запоминаю пресет который был у объекта до наведения мыши
            $('#block-views-catalog-block-1').animate({scrollTop: $('#clickhover').offset().top}, 1300); //прокручиваю до якоря
        }
        for(var i = 0; i< result._objects.length; i++){ //пока не пройдусь по всем объектам
            //проверяю сколько объектов на карте соответствует этому лоту
            if(result._objects[i].properties._data.hintContent ==  e.get('target').properties._data.hintContent){
                if(e.get('target').options._options.preset != 'custom#blockhover') //если клик совершен не второй раз по тому же геообъекту
                    OldPresetByClick = OldPresetByHover; //запоминаю пресет который был у объекта до наведения мыши
                result._objects[i].options.set('preset', 'custom#blockhover');    //каждому найденному объекту на карте меняю пресет   
            }
        }
    });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему прокрутка работает некорректно и как это можно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

Не работает, т.к. `offset()` элемента разный при каждом положении прокрутки внутри контейнера.

Надо учитывать текущий скролл контейнера.

```
jQuery('#block-views-catalog-block-1').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery('#clickhover').position().top+jQuery('#block-views-catalog-block-1').scrollTop()
}, 1300);
```

И я взял `position()`, чтобы он считал относительно родителя, а не страницы.